# Why Disk image file on host computer doesn't decrease when I delete huge files in virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I installed CentOS on the virtualbox(Host OS is Windows 7). I created the disk image file that is VDI files(**dynamically allocated image**). Recently,when  I delete huge files in CentOS,the VDI file on my disk doesn't decrease. Why? How to tackle this problem?

Comment: Dynamically allocated doesn't mean it shrinks. It just grows if needed.

Comment: never shrink?how to shrink the size of file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirtualBox does not automatically reclaim disk space (on host) when you delete files within the VM. To shrink the disk image, you need to

First, zero out all free spaces (for all partitions and Logical Volumes on the HDD) and then turn the VM off.

`cat /dev/zero > z;sync;sleep 3;sync;rm -f z`

Then, use the following command to compact the VDI.

`VBoxManage modifyhd /path/to/image.vdi --compact`

[VBox Doc](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi)

> With the --compact option, can be used to compact disk images, i.e. remove blocks that only contains zeroes. This will shrink a dynamically allocated image again; it will reduce the physical size of the image without affecting the logical size of the virtual disk. Compaction works both for base images and for diff images created as part of a snapshot.

BTW: For VMWare (.vmdk), you need to use `vmware-vdiskmanager -k xxx.vmdk` to do the same.

Comment: But I still have a question.What is the first line command's function?

Comment: Basically the 1st command fills free disk space with zeroes (a single file called z in the current working directory), then delete the file, make the VDI ready to be compacted.

Comment: sync;sleep 3;sync;  what does this command means?

Comment: `sync` flushes file system buffers to synchronize data on disk with memory. Sleep waits a few seconds. 2 `sync` invocations just to make sure the file is actually written on to the file system.

Comment: Thanks Terry Wang ... Can it be possible in RHEL KVM (virt-manager)?

Comment: Command cat /dev/zero > z generates a very very large file and my disk gets full. As a result I am unable to complete the operation and I have to kill it and delete the created z file. Any idea what would be the size of this file. My VirtualBox has CentOS and its vdi file is of 26gb size (actual size) and virtual size is 128gb. OR is there any easy way out step-by-step in many steps.

Comment: @user3282777 try to understand the full line `cat /dev/zero > z;sync;sleep 3;sync;rm -f z`

Answer (score 1):

How can the host know which sectors offered to the VM are being used by the VM and which are free?

The only thing it knows is when the VM requests a sector that still was not assigned in the disk file (when it increases it).

Maybe "defragmenting" or a similar procedure could reorganize disk usage well enough so that you could manually tell the host to reduce the space. So far, I do not know of any VM host that offers that feature, though (and using it would always be very risky).

The simplest alternative would be cloning your VM to a new one.

Comment: how to reorganize disk usage?

Comment: at least the host should compress the disk image. In that case clearing the disk (putting all zero's where a file was sitting) might increase compression